# How can I fix Heroku problem? I cannot deploy

Tags: heroku

I tried to deploy my project to Heroku, but I got the problem, I can not deploy.

[image]

Comment: Please share a gist of the error log and the repo you're working with.

Comment: Also, check if you have a file called `store.js` under `src/Redux/`

Comment: if you are using react then netlify or vercel are  best and quick options

Answer (score 0):

It can be related to the PORT. 
You can try to define the port like this:

```
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
```